# Bypass 3D payer-authentication OTP when using sale transaction with payment_token Cybersource

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing, cybersource

I'm working one of our company project which is related to taxi/careem/uber app. Now I've to implement cybersource credit/debit card service on the service api level.

I've found cybersource's secure-acceptance source code [GitHub](https://github.com/e-payment/cybersource-secure-acceptance/tree/master/php), which is based on web-application and best fit to our need. I've successfully convert this web-application to service api by preparing a `<form>` with the hidden input field and pass the form to Android/iOS webView which load the given form and redirects the user to 3D secure OTP screen.

My Question is, after getting the payment token by using

> passing payment_type: authorization,create_payment_token

next time on the time of

> payment_type: sale,
>
> payment_token: got from the above step.

it redirect me to again 3D OTP screen. Is there anyway to bypass this process when using `payment_type: sale,` ?

I want to implement this workflow because I don't want to show payer authentication screen next time to the user. Once user authorize at the time of registration, next time he can just tap to charge using his/her payment token.

Best Example: CAREEM & UBER APP

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late but how you would do is you would make the second call (transaction_type: sale) using a different profile where you have payer authentication disabled.